# How to search for strings in a process efficiently?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, process

I've seen tools such as Process Explorer that can list all the strings in a process that it is storing. I would like to simulate similar behavior in a C/C++ program. I'm using a Windows computer, so I know that there is functions from win32 to walk through a snapshot of the heap in a process. What I want to know is how I should efficiently scan for strings in memory like Process Explorer can.

Edit : Please no tool suggestions. I want to know how I should do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You want a tool such as "strings". Which I think is included in the sysinternals bundle. If not, there is probably a tool available in cygwin.

Comment: Hm. Isn't that a _tool_?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Get a "full access" token to the target process.
- Suspend it.
- Read mapped regions.
- Read the memory itself. Most likely encodings used: UTF-8 and UTF-16. If the constituent bytes build a valid 0-terminated string, and are only using a restricted alphabet (probably space, tab, \r \n, letters, punctuation and numbers), you have your string. Print it.
- Resume it.

Happy coding.